# JQuery 2.0 closest with context

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought that adding a DOM element as context to a JQuery method would restrict the method to looking ONLY at that element and its descendants instead of the entire document. If this is the case...

Why does this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var contextElem = document.getElementById("row1");
            $("img").closest(".drow", contextElem).each(function(index, elem) {
                console.log("Context Element: " + elem.tagName + " " + elem.className
                            + " " + elem.id);
            });    

        });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JQuery Closest Example</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <div id="oblock">        
            <div class="dtable">
                <div id="row1" class="drow">
                    <div class="dcell">
                        <img src="cell11.png"/><label for="cell11">Cell 1 1:</label>
                        <input name="cell11Value" value="0" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dcell">
                        <img src="cell12.png"/><label for="cell12">Cell 1 2:</label>
                        <input name="cell12Value" value="0" required >
                    </div>               
                </div>
                <div id="row2"class="drow">
                    <div class="dcell">
                        <img src="cell21.png"/><label for="cell21">Cell 2 1:</label>
                        <input name="cell21Value" value="0" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dcell">
                        <img src="cell22.png"/><label for="cell22">Cell 2 2:</label>
                        <input name="cell22Value" value="0" required >
                    </div>       
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonDiv"><button type="submit">Save</button></div>                    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
J
```

Result in this in the console:

Context Element: DIV drow row2

Instead of this:

Context Element: DIV drow row1

???

Comment: Fiddle showing what's happening along the way: http://jsfiddle.net/Pypy8/

Answer (score 1):

Passing in a context means jQuery will look for your selector as a descendent of `context`. In your case, your selector and `context` are the same element.

Comment: Right... but it isn't row2 or a parent of row2. how is row2 getting selected?

Comment: I agree, Kevin. It's definitely not intuitive from the documentation that the displayed behaviour is what you would expect.

Comment: So I can see how row1 isn't shown but, it seems like, no one can explain why row 2 does show. For extra fun, change the ID for the context to row2 and you'll see it display row1.

Comment: @aspro - what are you actually trying to accomplish?